# AWS - Scalability for our web site and App

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-auto-scaling

We have a PHP web site with admin login and Android App. We are using admin login to add/remove products in the web site and customers uses the App for purchasing items.

Currently we are using single VPS server for the same.

We are planning to move the production to AWS for high availability and scalability.

We decided to use RDS for MySQL DB but not sure how to host the application behind the loadbalancer and autoscaling as we may need to add/remove the items from admin panel.

Please share your thoughts on this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can host your PHP application in ec2 this way:

1. run ec2 t2.micro instance
2. install your PHP app and make sure it runs smoothly even just for calling from the instance public IP
3. create an AMI image of your t2.micro instance
4. create a load balancer add listener port 80
5. create a target group and assign it to your load balancer
6. create launch configuration with your AMI image
7. create an auto-scaling group and select your launch configuration 
8. add dynamic scaling policy

and if your domain is hosted on Route53, you can create an SSL with a certificate manager.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, If there is no change in the selling items then we can follow your steps. If we want to add a new item through admin login then it will difficult, correct? Every time we need to create a new AMI and create a new launch configuration?

Comment: The Admin changes to any of your selling items table will be reflected across your application.

For the launch configuration, you only create it once.